# product's models relationship in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, rails-models

I'm developing online shop for experience. I  stuck on modeling products relationship.

This is my example. (--> = "has_many"):

Country --> Labels(vendors) --> Collections --> Products

Models

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :labels
 has_many :collections, through: :labels
end

class Label < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :country
 has_many  :collections
end

class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :label
 has_one :country, through: :label, source: :country
 has_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :collection
 has_one :label, through: :collection, source: :label
 has_one :country, through: :label, source: :country
end
```

I should use every model like category or subcategory. Example

```
Brazil/SuperLabel/NightCollection/SuperProduct
```

But every product should have country, label and name of collection in description.Example

### SuperProduct

price: 100.0$

country: Brazil

collection: NightCollection

label: SuperLabel

I use this approach
`Product.all.includes(:country, :label, :collection)` , but i think this is wrong solution and not rails way.

Questions:

1) What other solutions are there? How i can fetch country of product, label of product and collection in product model? My solution is bad or not? maybe another approach or maybe another relationship between models

2) Controllers.Should i  use separate controllers for country, labels etc and create products with nested attributes (using created early variants) or use nested resources? If i use nested resources, what about this rule `Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep.` What the best solution?

1) for example

```
resources :countries  do
  resources :labels, only: [:new, :create]
end
resources :labels, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

resources :labels  do
  resources :collections, only: [:new, :create]
end
resources :collections, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

resources :collections  do
  resources :products, only: [:new, :create]
end
resources :products, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

I think it's a bit massive approach
  second solution:

```
resources :countries
resources :labels
resources :collections
resources :products
```

When i will create product i will add country, label etc , that i created early in country controller, label controller etc separately. I want  simple admin panel, without difficult links.

what is best approach and what pitfalls in every of this approaches? Maybe all approaches are  not good and exist another solutions.

Comment: ad. 1: You did not specify what you want to achieve. Try to explain it a bit more. ad. 2: You should use `ProductsController` to create products, `CountriesController` to create countries etc. Within every such controller, you can create as many nested attributes as you want, however it would be really tough to mantain. I would say, as `Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep`, same apply to nested attributes.

Comment: @blelump thx for your comment, q: how i can  fetch country of product, label of product and collection in product model? My solution is righ, or not? maybe another approach or maybe another relationship between models? and i ll edit my question

Comment: I've answered below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Product.all.includes(:country, :label, :collection)` simply fetches all products. You would also fetch by typing `Product.all.includes(:collection => [:label => :country])` (you do not need these `has_one` associations then) and it gives exactly the same result as the previous one. By result I mean not all products, but all remaining associations eager load with the same amount of queries.

Regarding model relationships, again, it depends what you need. The declaration of your relations is not as important as your database tables and indexes. Any `has_one` or `has_many` is just to tell `ActiveRecord`, how to associate `model A` with `model B` and fetch data eventually. What's important here, you're already using `includes` for eager loading.